# is it possible to open specific viewcontroller(containing app) after tap on extension(today extension)?

Tags: ios, today-extension

I am using Today extension in ios.

I have multiple view controller with different info. and I am displaying some info in tableview using  Today extension. when click on row then I want to open related viewcontroller with info.

I have tried following code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ReadText://"];
      [self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];

   }
```

I have set url schemes in info.plist

but using this code I can only open root viewcontroller.

appreciate for help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can open the customViewController progrmattically by passing custom data to urlSchemes.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ReadText://customViewController"];
```

Implement the delegate method and get the string from `url` and than push the `customViewController` progrmattically.

```
 -(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
       NSString *viewController =  [[url host] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       if([viewController isEqualToString:@"customViewController"]) {
          //push customViewController on rootViewController
       }
  }
```

Comment: actual problem is app delegate method doesn't called?

Comment: try applicationdidfinishlaunching with NSURL *url = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];

Comment: If the app delegate method doesn't get called, then either (a) you didn't configure the URL scheme properly, or (b) you're calling the wrong URL scheme (maybe you mistyped it?).